# pyparsing to group matched string and unmatched stings in the same order the input text

Tags: python, match, pyparsing

I have a problem in parsing my expression string. I want to identify all the identifiers from the input string using pyparsing.

`identifier=pyparsing_common.identifier`

My input string is

```
identifier.parseString('1+2*xyz*abc/5')
```

I want the below as output

```
[['1+2*'],['xyz'],['*'],['abc'],['/5']]
```

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a number of different code samples to show some alternative ways to tackle your problem (using pyparsing version 2.4.7).

Using your definitions of `input_string` and `identifier`:

```
>>> input_string = "1+2*xyz*abc/5"
>>> identifier = pp.pyparsing_common.identifier
```

Using `identifier.split()` (similar to `re.split`) to get the parts of the input string:

```
>>> print(list(identifier.split(input_string, includeSeparators=True)))
['1+2*', 'xyz', '*', 'abc', '/5']
```

Using `identifier.searchString()` to return a ParseResults for each match:

```
>>> print(identifier.searchString(input_string))
[['xyz'], ['abc']]
```

Using the `sum()` built-in to combine the matches into a single ParseResults:

```
>>> print(sum(identifier.searchString(input_string)))
['xyz', 'abc']
```

Using the `locatedExpr` helper method to wrap `identifier`, so that each
match produces a group containing the matched value, plus the start and
end locations:

```
>>> print(sum(pp.locatedExpr(identifier).searchString(input_string)))
[[4, 'xyz', 7], [8, 'abc', 11]]
```

Using `dump()` to show the values as a list, and the named results in each
subgroup:

```
>>> print(sum(pp.locatedExpr(identifier).searchString(input_string)).dump())
[[4, 'xyz', 7], [8, 'abc', 11]]
[0]:
  [4, 'xyz', 7]
  - locn_end: 7
  - locn_start: 4
  - value: 'xyz'
[1]:
  [8, 'abc', 11]
  - locn_end: 11
  - locn_start: 8
  - value: 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer I doubt it may not be effective but, it works as expected.

```
   from pyparsing import pyparsing_common
   identifier=pyparsing_common.identifier
   input_string='1+2*xyz*abc/5'
   b=0
   split_array=[]
   for match, start, stop in identifier.scanString(input_string):
       split_array.append(input_string[b:start])
       split_array.append(input_string[start:stop])
       b=stop
       print(match, start, stop)
   split_array.append(input_string[b:])
   print(split_array)
```

The output is

```
['xyz'] 4 7
['abc'] 8 11
['1+2*', 'xyz', '*', 'abc', '/5']
```

**I would still request someone to validate and provide a better solution if you have.**

Thank you.